# Oracle SQL - Check duplicates in whole table

Tags: sql, oracle, duplicates

I have a table with columns

```
BIN_1_1
BIN_1_2
BIN_1_3
```

all the way to `BIN_10_10`

The user enter a value, and the value needs to be checked in all the columns starting from BIN_1_1 to BIN_10_10.

If there is a duplicate value, it prints a msg and gets out of the procedure / function.

How do I go about this?

Comment: User enter single value and you want to check if it occur in any colum or user input whole row and you want to check if every inputed column not exist in whole table?

Comment: user enters a single value, that needs to be checked in all the columns data.

Comment: How about creating unique index on each column? Then try to enter value in every column `insert into tab (col1, ...colN) values(val, val, val...val)`. Exception = duplicate exists somwhere, no exception = no duplicates. Do rollback and print msg

Comment: Is this something your users will do often? If so, you may be better off unpivoting the table (either as a base table or a view - perhaps an on commit refresh fast materialized view). On the unpivoted table, you can do a trivial "COUNT(*) FROM ... WHERE val = :user_input".

Comment: By the way, are all the columns the same data type? If they aren't, the assignment is quite a bit more complicated.

Comment: All are same data type.

Comment: @KonstantinSorokin - that approach will miss duplicates that happen to be in the same row.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you mean something like this?

```
create or replace
procedure check_duplicate( p_val yourtable.bin_1_1%type) is
  v_dupl number;
begin
  begin
    select 1 into v_dupl from yourtable
    where p_val in (bin_1_1, bin_1_2, ... bin_10_10) and rownum <=1;
  exception 
     when no_data_found
        then v_dupl := 0;
  end;
  if v_dupl = 1
  then
      dbms_output.put_line('your message about duplication');
      return;
  else
      dbms_output.put_line('here you can do anything');      
  end if;
end;
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this query,

```
INSERT INTO yourTable values ('your values') where  
     WHERE BIN_1_1 NOT IN (
         SELECT bins FROM (
                               SELECT BIN_1_1 FROM yourTable
                               UNION
                               SELECT BIN_1_2 FROM yourTable
                               UNION
                               SELECT BIN_1_3 FROM yourTable
                             ) AS bins
                          )
```

P.S. I din't run this query.

Answer (score 0):

Unpivot your table, then it's easy. You may want to write a query that will write the query below for you. ("Dynamic" SQL just to save yourself some work.)

```
select case when count(*) > 1 then 'Duplicate Found' end as result
from   ( select * 
         from   your_table
         unpivot (val for col in (BIN_1_1, BIN_1_2, ........, BIN_10_10))
       )
where  val = :user_input;
```

Here :user_input is a bind variable - use whatever mechanism works for you (end-user interface, SQL Developer, whatever).

You need to decide what outcome you want when the value is not duplicated in the table - you didn't mention anything about that.